# Pixel perfect alignment of wxPython widgets?

Tags: python, user-interface, alignment, wxpython

#### Summary:

I'm trying to align multiple wxPython widgets horizontally at the bottom of a [BoxSizer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.BoxSizer.html), but they are off by just a pixel as seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem (not enough reputation to embed the image here)]

As you can see, the [BitmapToggleButton](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.BitmapToggleButton.html) is positioned one pixel higher than the [TextCtrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html) widget. The wxPython [inspection tool](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Widget%20Inspection%20Tool) says the Button is even two pixels higher, but in the screenshot, it's only one. I think this has something to do with border calculation, but I don't know.

If I omit the alignment flags in the code below, the widgets get aligned to the center, but the Button is still a pixel off in the opposite direction.

#### Code:

```py
header = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

self.label_user = wx.StaticText(panel, label="User:")
self.input_user = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
self.edit_user = wx.BitmapToggleButton(panel, label=img_edit, style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT)

header.Add(...) # more widgets that are not bottom-aligned
header.Add(self.label_user, flag=wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
header.Add(5, -1)
header.Add(self.input_user, flag=wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)
header.Add(self.lock_user, flag=wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM)

main_sizer.Add(header, flag=wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, border=views.constants.MARGIN)
```

Comment: Try overriding the size `        self.edit_user = wx.BitmapToggleButton(panel, -1, label=img_edit, style=wx.BU_EXACTFIT, size=(26,26))` although the image will be slightly clipped at the bottom.